CNOT gate when the target qubit is in entangled state
I want to understand how to derive the result of applying a CNOT gate to a state where the target qubit is in an entangled or Bell state. I have read that the first qubit remains the same, as expected for a CNOT gate, the second qubit remains unchanged and the third qubit is reversed. Is this the a logical sequence?
I am very new to quantum computing so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm assuming you have three qubits $q_0, q_1, q_2$.
$q_0, q_1$ are initialized in the Bell state: $|q_1q_0\rangle = \sqrt{1/2}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$.
$q_2$ is initialized in state $|1\rangle$, therefore your initial state is:
$$|q_2q_1q_0\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}(|100\rangle + |111\rangle). $$
If a $CX$ gate is applied with the control in $q_2$ and the target on $q_0$, the final state is given by:
$$CX_{20}|q_2q_1q_0\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}(|101\rangle + |110\rangle). $$
Not quite sure if this is what you had in mind, but seems to fit the sequence of events you described.
